# SQL Server - Substring directory path

Tags: sql-server, string

I have some directories saved like this in a table. The column is a varchar type and the strings are separated by /

```
'/Invoices/April/2012'
'/Expenses/2017/June/01'
'/Taxes/Company/'
```

How can I get a substring in order to get only

```
'/Invoices'
'/Expenses'
'/Taxes'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourColumn, 0, CHARINDEX('/', YourColumn, 2))
FROM YourTable
```

Edit:  Yes, `CHARINDEX()` is 1-based, not 0-based.  Yes, I hate it too.